# Approach to post-hoc test for factors in a regressions (in R)

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, post-hoc

I have a problem with some analysis I need to do.

I have a series of regressions. Some of the predictors of these regression are categorical with multiple levels. I performed regressions, both linear and logistic, choosing a baseline for these category according to various factors.

The problem is that my colleagues asked not only for a confrontation of the factors to a baseline but also a pairwise confrontation. Like you it's used to do with a post-hoc test for ANOVA (they are pretty new to regressions and their benefits).

How should I approach this?
I thought of some solutions:

- Subsetting: That is subset the data to include two factors at time, and therefore repeating the regression once per every subset.
- Splitting: Splitting the category column in a column for every factor and put 0 and 1 as levels. This approach can furthermore be conducted in two ways:

  - Putting all the new columns in the regression (minding that they are mutually exclusive).
  - Putting one column at time, multiplying the regressions.

Which approach would you suggest, minding statistical correctness and workload?

Especially, what's the conceptual difference between the three methods?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe have a look at `multcomp` package for post-hoc testing {`glht` function]

Comment: you should post it as an answer. An even better answer would be explain also the problems with the above mentioned methods.

Comment: what is the post hoc approach?